# Is it possible for a sequence of random variable to converge to two different non-degenerate limit?

Tags: probability-theory

Let's say we have a sequence of random variables $X_n$. Let $a_n^{(1)}, b_n^{(1)}, a_n^{(2)}, b_n^{(2)}$ be sequences of deterministic positive numbers.

Assuming that $b_n^{(1)}/b_n^{(2)} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, is it possible that
$$
\frac{X_n - a_n^{(1)}}{b_n^{(1)}} \overset{d}{\to} Y_1
$$
and
$$
\frac{X_n - a_n^{(2)}}{b_n^{(2)}} \overset{d}{\to} Y_2
$$
such that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are two different non-degenerate random variables?
More precisely, is it possible that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are not constant a.s., and the total variation distance between them are not $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This is the conclusion of Theorem 1 on p.40 of Gnedenko and Kolmogorov's *Limit distributions*, or of what Loeve calls a "Convergence of types theorem" (on p. 203 of his *Probability Theory*, 3d ed.)   After centering and scaling, all non-degenerate limit distributions of a sequence of distributions are of the same "type", that is, are related as $F$ and $G$ are when $F(x)=G(ax+b)$ for all $x$, for some finite $a\ne0$ and $b$.  The proof is not hard.  Everyone attibutes the result to Khinchin, but I don't have a precise reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make each $X_i$ be uniform on $[0, 1]$.

Let $b^{(1)}_n = n, b^{(2)}_n = 1$.

Let $a^{(1)}_n = a^{(2)}_n = 0$.

Then the first sequence converges to $X_1 = 0$, while the second converges to a  rv that's uniform on $[0, 1]$.

N.B.: It appears that you've used $X_1$ to denote both the first element of your sequence, *and* the first limit (and similarly for $X_2$). If that was intentional, which seems unlikely, then I need to modify my answer to this:

"Make each $X_i$ be uniform on $[0, 1]$, except make $X_2$ be the everywhere-zero rv."

Comment: Yeah, I should not use $X_1$ and $X_2$ as the limit. I changed it. But in your example, one limit is degenerate. I am asking if it's possible to have two different non-degenerate limits.

Comment: I missed the keyword "non-degenerate" -- sorry.